# Button Image Path is not focusing in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I have a close button. My requirement is that when a user mouse goes over the button the button background color will change.

I have a path inside the button for "X" symbol. When mouseover the path is the background is changing is working correctly. But very near to mouse over the path then only the background color is changed.

So please could anyone suggest how to resolve this,

**MyStyleCode:**

```
<Style x:Key="closeButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="bd">
                    <Path Margin="0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8"
                          Stroke="White"
                          StrokeThickness="2" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Button**

```
<Button Grid.Column="1"
        Width="40"
        Height="25"
        Margin="0,0,5,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource closeButtonStyle}"
        ToolTip="Close" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `Style.Triggers` for your `Button`. Not to your `Content` alone (`Path` for your case). Like,

```
<Style x:Key="closeButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Path Margin="0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8"
                          Stroke="Black"
                          StrokeThickness="2" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```